# Login in Django 1.5

Tags: python, django, email, authentication

I use MyUser model in Django 1.5 with e-mail login:
model:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
    )
    last_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    second_name=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    post=models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    objects = MyUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['last_name','first_name','second_name','post', ....]

    def get_full_name(self):
       return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
       return self.email

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
       return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
       return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

I tried method with from django.contrib.auth.views import login:

urls:

```
(r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'enter.html'}),
```

view: nothing.

It works for superuser from classic User model, not for MyUser.

Then I tried:

view:

```
def login_view(request):
    username = request.POST['email']
    password = request.POST['password']
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None and user.is_active:
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/n1.html")# Redirect to a success page.
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/account/invalid/")# Return a 'disabled account' error message
```

template:

```
{% if form.errors %}
<p>Something is wrong</p>
{% endif %}

<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="email">Login:</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" value="" id="email"/>
    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="username">

    <input type="submit" value="login" />
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{next|escape}}" />

</form>
```

urls:

```
(r'^login/$', login_view, {'template_name': 'enter.html'}),
```

But I got error `login_view() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_name'`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you pass a template name in `urls.py` and where do you use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`login_view() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_name'` means that your view function should have `template_name` parameter:

```
def login_view(request, template_name):
   'your code'
```

If you don't need it, don't pass it in urls.py:

```
(r'^login/$', login_view),
```

Upd.

Your `login_view` handles your POST method. You can re-write it this way to render form on GET

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/n1.html")
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/account/invalid/")
    form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'enter.html', {'login_form': LoginForm})
```

Comment: But how can I get my enter.html template?

Comment: @Wolter See the `login_view` function defined here. If you pass `template_name` in `urls.py`, you can get it in your function as defined here.

Comment: I don't understand why from django.contrib.auth.views import login (r'^login/$', login, {'template_name': 'enter.html'}), is workin, but from views import login_view (r'^login/$', login_view, {'template_name': 'enter.html'}), not working?

Comment: I mean error login_view() got an unexpected keyword argument 'template_name'. Where can I import LoginForm()? Thx!

Comment: Compare django [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/views.py). It's not mandatory to  use forms but highly recommended. Forms are explained in django docs.

Comment: I found LoginForm() only in very old snippet http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/332/